# numberOfRowsInSection if inside Switch

Tags: swift, uitableview, if-statement, enums, switch-statement

I have this numberOfRowsInSection.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch Section(rawValue: section)! {
        case .slider: return parentVC.selectedCommunity == nil ? 1 : 0
        case .header: return 1
        case .item:
            if case item = PostType.survey.rawValue {
                let sectionItems = parentVC.surveys
                var numberOfRows: Int = sectionItems.count
                for rowItems in sectionItems {
                    numberOfRows += rowItems.surveyAnswers!.count
                }
                return numberOfRows
            } else { return cellTypes.count }
        }
    }
```

I want to check if .item is PostType.survey
I have tried to show the logic with not working code. if case item = PostType.survey.rawValue { this statement does not work to catch

How can I detect it?

```
enum Section: Int {
        case slider
        case header
        case item

        static var numberOfSections: Int { return Section.item.rawValue + 1 }
        
        var reuseIdentifier: String {
            switch self {
            case .slider: return NewsFeedSliderTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier
            case .header: return NewsFeedPostHeaderTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier
            case .item: return NewsfeedTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier
            }
        }
    }
     

enum PostType: Int {
    case post = 0
    case question = 1
    case survey = 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `if case item = PostType.survey.rawValue` but item is a enum case inside of `Section`.

From looking you code, I assume you want to check if `section == item.rawValue` then after that you check `Section.item.rawValue == PostType.survey.rawValue` or not.

But as an enum case, `Section.item.rawValue = 2` and `PostType.survey.rawValue = 2` is always = 2 unless you define differently. So if you compare with `section` which is `Int` in your code. The `else` in your condition in `.item` which is `return cellTypes.count` will never be executed.

So instead using `if case item = PostType.survey.rawValue {`

You can change to `if case section = PostType.survey.rawValue {` because the thing you need to compare here is `rawValue` which is an `Int` or completely remove the condition because both `rawValue` of `item` and `survey` are the same.